# full calendar div rerender event not working after dropping external event on calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, visualforce

I am currently facing an issue when rerendering information for events after dropping events on calendar. When I try to use rerender events or refetchevents, nothing happens.

```
eventReceive: function(event) { // called when a proper external event is dropped
            //dropevent(event.id,event.resourceId);
            event.end= moment(event.start.toDate(), "DD-MM-YYYY").add('days', 1);
            Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.EventSchedulerCntrl2.dropEventOnCalendar}',
            event.id,event.title,event.start.toDate(), event.resourceId, 
            function(result, event){
                //$( this ).dialog( "close" );
               // window.location.reload();
            }, 
            {escape: true}
            );   
            j$('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
            loadCalendar();
            refreshMyPanel();
            console.log('eventReceive', event);
        },
```

I need to fetch event information once store on backend. I tried by using visualforce page actionfunction for rerendering section but doesn't work.

Comment: show us what you do (code?), what you expect and what happens instead, and give error messages, if any.

Comment: Just edit and update please check and let me know if you can help with this issue. Thanks in advance